# Loosing context inside the callback

Tags: javascript, angular, this

I have a service which has this method:

```
public register(user, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    });

    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.apiURL}/users/register`, user, { observe: 'response', headers: httpHeaders }).subscribe(
        (response) => successCallback(response),
        (error) => errorCallback(error)
    );
  }
```

I am calling that service method from a component

```
this.apiService.register(this.user, function(response) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login', { state: { registered: true } })
      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

On the line where I call `this.router.navigateByUrl` I am getting this error:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined`

I understand that this is not defined, but I am not sure what is the proper way of using this within a callback.

Any advice?

Comment: Replace the `function() {...}` with the fat arrow `() => {...}` that way it binds to *its* lexical environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to solve it:

- ES6 way : Replace the `function() {...}` with the fat arrow `() => {...}` that way it binds to *its* lexical environment.
- ES5 way : Use .bind to *bind* the execution context for this function.

  ```
   this.apiService.register(this.user, function(response) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login', { state: { registered: true } })
   }.bind(this), function(error) {
     console.log(error);
   });
  ```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference to "this" outside the callback function.

```
let outerThis = this;
this.apiService.register(this.user, function(response) {
    outerThis.router.navigateByUrl('/login', { state: { registered: true } })
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: I knew about this one, but I wanted to avoid it. Anyway, thanks for posting!